# C++ detect any constructor with SFINAE

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

I tried to create a template class that should detect any constructor by using SFINAE and variadic templates. Here is code of the template:

```
template <typename Type, typename ... Arguments>
struct IsConstructible
    {

        template <typename U, decltype(U(Arguments...))* = nullptr>
        static char test();
        template <typename U>
        static long test(...);

        static constexpr bool value = sizeof(test<Type>()) == sizeof(char);

    };
```

However, when I test this with following type:

```
struct MyBadType {

    MyBadType(int x) { }

};
```

the result of this:

```
IsConstructible<MyBadType, int>::value;
```

is 0. Is there anything wrong with my template checker? I am using MSVS 2015 express.

Comment: start with replacing `U(Arguments...)` by `U(std::declval<Arguments>()...)`, and then adding an `int` parameter to `char test(int)` (followed by `sizeof(test<Type>(0))` )

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Answers go in the answer box.

Answer (score 3):

The code shouldn't compile; if MSVC does so then it's using extensions.

```
template <typename U, decltype(U(Arguments...))* = nullptr>
```

That `decltype` expression doesn't make sense. `U(Arguments...)` is a function type, but you want to get the type of constructing a `U` from `Arguments...`. You could use `std::declval` for that:

```
template <typename U, decltype(U(std::declval<Arguments>()...))* = nullptr>
```

There is a second issue:

```
    template <typename U, decltype(U(std::declval<Arguments>()...))* = nullptr>
    static char test();
    template <typename U>
    static long test(...);
```

A call of `test<type>()` would be ambiguous. The "classic" way to resolve the ambiguity is to give the preferred version a dummy parameter:

```
    template <typename U, decltype(U(std::declval<Arguments>()...))* = nullptr>
    static char test(int);
    //          here ^^^
    template <typename U>
    static long test(...);
```

Then you call the function like `test<type>(0)`.

[<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/81ae45aa6faeb67a)

---

See [this blog post](https://rmf.io/cxx11/overload-ranking/) for a more flexible way to resolve overload ambiguities.

Comment: About that dummy parameter, should not (...) overload be always last to choose from? If so, how is that ambiguous to call test()?

Comment: @AlexanderBily it's a *conversion* from something to an ellipsis that is considered as the worst choice, not *selecting* an overload with `...` itself